# Whatsapp notification bubble on app icon: change to look like Apple ios 15 i.e. RED and NUMBER of UNREAD MESSAGES ? So prominent

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, ios

Android 12 Motorola.

Is it possible to display the number of unread messages in a prominent color - preferably a RED and the NUMBER of UNREAD messages ?

This would make it much more prominent once the phone is unlocked.

Also, when unlocked the message appears on the screen then intermediately disappears: on ios I can make it permanent - until dismissed.

Admittedly on the lock screen it does display the unread WhatsApp: this is for a user that is not so familiar with smart phones and does not use one enough to get used to it properly.

Comment: Do you mean "RED" or "READ"?

Comment: Yes, I do mean the **color red** ! The UI is proprietary /written by google in Java ? Can a red large circle with a number for the number of unread(!) messages be displayed ? Or is this functionality that cannot be added ? By changing code, overlaying, or in settings. The message does not remain on the screen when unlocked! The prominent badge for unread messages of ios 15 is far better. Please only responses from people that can offer a solution.